# Clickatell HTTP API send message fails with Routing Error (Status 9)

Tags: clickatell

I have recently converted a trial account into a paid starter package and, since I've been assigned a long number, my attempts to send messages via the HTTP API have failed with the following messages in the Message Reports console:

An error occurred while attempting to route the message

Routing error (status 9)

I have confirmed that my username, password, and api id are entered correctly and that the long number has been matched to the active API. I've tried the "Valid Sample Code" provided on the API management console, all with the same result. Below are a few failed message ids if that's helpful for anyone on the Clickatell team.

6d7868662782cfd7d1708996bca066b1
4f837467ed535521ef39d9d885f121f9
2be08f4663a3d9d7cf2e5b9e9cad2d5f

For what it's worth, my trial account worked fine and as expected, so I'm fairly certain that this is not (obvious) user error on my part. I also upgraded a few hours ago; I'm not sure if there is a wait period between account activation and functional service. Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting mo=1 and using your long number as your sender id from=123456789?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

make sure you dont add any programming symbols in the text message. i had an exclamation mark and it gave me a status 9 error.

```
http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=xxxx&user=xxxx&from=13055140341&mo=1&password=xxxx&to=xxxx&text=xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I encountered a very similar problem with the REST API. It also requires the undocumented "mo=1" and "from=[your long number]" fields to be included.

Also, in the FAQ, they have "MO=1" but in actuality, it has to be a lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

From OP:

> Clickatell support responded with the following advice that resolved my problem. I also changed the password on my API key during the process which seemed to be part of the issue.
>
> http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=xxxx&user=xxxx&from=13055140341&mo=1&password=xxxx&to=xxxx&text=xxxx
>
> "from" is your long number, and because I'm using 2 way messaging , mo=1 needed to be set also. It would have been helpful if this were in the exemplary code provided on the api info and help section, but alas, I had to go through support to get my answer. It took about 2 business days for the response, but they were helpful